# Adding a non-domain Member to the Google Developer's Console

Tags: google-app-engine

We have hired a firm to complete a project in the Google Cloud Platform and need to add their development lead as an Editing Member to our Developer Console so they can create and manage the project.

When trying to add their lead by email address I get a warning that I cannot add a non-domain member. Obviously they do not have an email address with our domain.

I've crawled through the permissions in our Google Apps Admin console and cannot find a setting for this. We would prefer to add them without having to add another user to our Google Apps For Work account.

Does anyone know how to add anyone to the Google Developer's Console from outside of our Google Apps domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To workaround this, you can do the following:

- Have the domain Administrator for your domain [Google Apps Account](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/2464926?hl=en) create a Google Group (say the group name is "GAE").
- Have the domain Administrator [allow out-of-domain members](https://support.google.com/a/answer/167097?hl=en&ref_topic=25841) for the group "GAE".
- Add the email addresses of out-of-domain members to group "GAE".
- Add group "GAE" to the project.
- There will be no confirmation email sent.

Once this is done, within 24 hours group membership propagates such that your Google App Engine Project becomes aware of the new group membership and allows its members access.

Comment: Excellent - Thank you!  I have completed the steps above.  Is there something I can provide to the members of that group on how to access the project in the Google Developer's Console?

Comment: Keep in mind it may take up to 24 hours before they can access. Otherwise they can log into your project with the emails you added to the project. They will see the same as you do.

Comment: Ryan - the Google group invitation propagated within 24 hours and our development lead was able to access the Project. Many thanks!